# Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I would like to understand whether this improper integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}dx$$
converges or diverges.

On one hand, if I fix $\alpha>0$, I note that
$$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}dx=0$$
since the integrand is odd, and the integration interval is symmetric with respect to the origin. On the other hand, however, Mathematica, when given the command

> Integrate[x*(Sin[x]/x)^2, {x, -[Infinity], [Infinity]}],

responds that the integral does not converge on $(-\infty, \infty)$. Does anyone have any suggestions to offer?

Comment: This computation $$\lim_{\alpha \to +\infty}\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}dx$$can be called the "principal value" of the integral.  As you note, this can exist even if the integral itself diverges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, for any function $f$ the improper integral $\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}} f(x)\ dx$ converges iff both $\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{c} f(x)\ dx}$ and $\displaystyle{\int_{c}^{+\infty}f(x)\ dx}$ converge for some number $c$. That is not the case with $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$ ([see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761692/why-does-int-1-infty-frac-sin2xx-mathrm-d-x-diverge)).

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int\limits_\pi^\infty {2\sin^2x\over x}\,dx $ does not converge. Indeed, we have
$2\sin^2x=1-\cos(2x)$ and the integral $\int\limits_\pi^\infty {\cos(2x)\over x}\,dx$ does converge, due to the Dirichlet test. However the integral $\int\limits_\pi^\infty {1\over x}\,dx$ does not converge hence the first mentioned integral is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice way to prove that this integral does not converge. You can split your integral like:
\begin{equation}
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx=
\int^{+\infty}_{1} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx+\int^{-1}_{-\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx+\int^{1}_{-1} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx
\end{equation}
The divergence of first two integrals can be proven by: (similarly for the second one)
\begin{equation}
\int^{+\infty}_{1}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx=\\
\int^{+\infty}_{1}\frac{\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}}{x}dx=\\
\int^{+\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{2x}dx-\int^{+\infty}_{1}\frac{\cos(2x)}{x}dx
\end{equation}
The first integral in the end does not converge, and the second one does, meaning the integral does not converge. I used the formula for a square of $\sin(x)$. The second integral convergence can be easily proven by ***Dirichlet's test*** by taking $f(x)=\cos(2x)$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2x}$, integrating over intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$. When it comes to third integral, we have a singularity at 0, so it would not be proper to follow the same pattern. Instead, just show that $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$ is continuous on the interval $[-1,1]$, which means that an integral exists and is finite.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}=0
\end{equation}

---

The problem with your reasoning is that if you have the integral
\begin{equation}
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
it does not have to be in the form you have written:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\alpha \to +\infty}\int^{\alpha}_{-\alpha}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
but can be expressed as, for example, like this:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\alpha \to +\infty}\int^{\alpha}_{-\alpha^2}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
This way, your integral would diverge, because it's bound "moves to $-\infty$ much faster than to $+\infty$". You should always use criteria and tests to check the convergence of these integrals.

Comment: What do you mean by integrating over the singularity at $x=0$ in the two integrals you end up with? You may elaborate on that.

Comment: @Gary Is the explanation better now? I have changed the boundaries of the integrals. This should be more precise.

Comment: Much better. Note that in the formula before "The first integral in the end does not converge" the integral should be from $1$ and not from $-\infty$.

Comment: @Gary Changed. I have modified the solution, so I letf it by mistake. Thanks!